# How can I randomize the iteration sequence of a Set?

Tags: java

I need to use the *Set* collection.

Each time I start a jvm to run the program, I want to iterate through the items in the *Set* in a randomly decided sequence.

The iteration sequence has nothing to do with the sequence in which I placed them in the *Set*, right?

So, what to do? How can I randomize the iteration sequence in a Set?

Here is my method, and it does not randomize.

```
public static <T> void shuffle(Set<T> set) {
        List<T> shuffleMe = new ArrayList<T>(set);
        Collections.shuffle(shuffleMe);
        set.clear();
        set.addAll(shuffleMe);
    }
```

Comment: Collections.shuffle() will ramdomize your list by modifying the list. However Set is already randomized.

Comment: @18bytes "Set" is not randomized. Each time I start a new jvm instance the sequence is always the same.

Comment: `Set` is unordered, what you are experiencing is the results of using the `hashCode` of the objects to put them in buckets.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson - to clarify, it's actually `HashSet` that is unordered; `Set` is just the interface (which may have an ordered implementation - see my answer for info)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### What you need is a RandomizingIterator

`Set` is unordered, so *randomizing* an unordered `Collection` doesn't make any logical sense.

An *ordered* `Set` is ordered using a `Comparator` which means it has a fixed order, you can't shuffle it, that has no meaning as the order is determined by the `Comparator` or the `compare()` method.

`Set` -> `List` will allow you to *shuffle* the contents of the `List` and then use a custom `RandomizingIterator` to iterate across the `Set`.

### Example Implementation :

Link to Gist on GitHub - [TestRandomizingIterator.java](https://gist.github.com/jarrodhroberson/8838728)

```
import org.junit.Test;

import javax.annotation.Nonnull;
import java.util.*;

public class TestRandomzingIterator
{
    @Test
    public void testRandomIteration()
    {
        final Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>()
        {
            /** Every call to iterator() will give a possibly unique iteration order, or not */
            @Nonnull
            @Override
            public Iterator<String> iterator()
            {
                return new RandomizingIterator<String>(super.iterator());
            }

            class RandomizingIterator<T> implements Iterator<T>
            {
                final Iterator<T> iterator;

                private RandomizingIterator(@Nonnull final Iterator<T> iterator)
                {
                    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
                    while(iterator.hasNext())
                    {
                        list.add(iterator.next());
                    }
                    Collections.shuffle(list);
                    this.iterator = list.iterator();
                }

                @Override
                public boolean hasNext()
                {
                    return this.iterator.hasNext();
                }

                @Override
                public T next()
                {
                    return this.iterator.next();
                }

            /**
             * Modifying this makes no logical sense, so for simplicity sake, this implementation is Immutable.
             * It could be done, but with added complexity.
             */
            @Override
            public void remove()
            {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("TestRandomzingIterator.RandomizingIterator.remove");
            }
            }
        };

        set.addAll(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C"));

        final Iterator<String> iterator = set.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println(iterator.next());
        }
    }
}
```

#### Notes:

This is a straw man example, but the intention is clear, use a custom `Iterator` to get custom iteration.

You can't get the *normal* iteration behavior back, but that doesn't seem to be a problem with your use case.

Passing the the `super.iterator()` to the facade is important, it will `StackOverflowError` otherwise, because it becomes a recursive call if you pass `this` to `.addAll()` or the `List()` constructor.

`HashSet` may appear to be *ordered* but it isn't guaranteed to stay ordered, the order depends on the `hashCode` of the objects and adding a single object *may* reorder the how the contents are order, the contract of the `Set` interface is that the order is **undefined** and in particular the `HashSet` is nothing more than a Facade over a backing `Map.keySet()`.

There are other more supposedly *light weight*, but much more complex solutions that use the original `Iterator` and try and keep track of what has already been seen, those solutions aren't improvements over this technique unless the size of the data is excessively large, and the you are probably looking at on disk structures at that point.

Comment: continuation from the `Set` javadoc: "unless this set is an instance of some class that provides a guarantee"

Comment: A guarantee of order, by definition that order can't be changed, or shuffled. And `Collections.shuffle()` requires a `List` it won't take a `Set`. They want to randomize the order, which is exactly the **opposite** of *guarantee* the order!

Comment: Yes, Collections.shuffle takes a list - see my answer for a code sample that takes the shuffled list from the question and dumps it into a `Set` that maintains that shuffled order.

Comment: the `Set` -> `List` -> `Set` shuffle isn't needed in this case.

Comment: With all the updates, this is a nice solution; it avoids one of the two 'copy the entire collection' steps present in the original question and my answer

Comment: yeah! I got it. The example code was very instructive. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could copy the contents of the `Set` into a `List`, shuffle the `List`, then return a new `LinkedHashSet` populated from the shuffled list. Nice thing about `LinkedHashSet` is that its iterators return elements in the order they were inserted.

```
public static <T> Set<T> newShuffledSet(Collection<T> collection) {
    List<T> shuffleMe = new ArrayList<T>(collection);
    Collections.shuffle(shuffleMe);
    return new LinkedHashSet<T>(shuffleMe);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Internally HashSet sorts all its elements, AFAIR according to their `hash()` value. So you should use other classes like `SortedSet` with a custom `comparator`. But remember the whole idea of `Set` is to find elements quickly, that's why it sorts elements internally. So you have to keep "stability" of the comparison. Maybe you don't need a set after shuffling?

Comment: I see the solution as holding the data in a Set. To randomly iterate, I'll place references to the Set items in a List, shuffle the List, then give whoever wants to iterate an unmodifiableList view of the randomized List.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#iterator%28%29) for java.util.Set:

> The elements are returned in no particular order (unless this set is an instance of some class that provides a guarantee).

When you insert the elements there is no guarantee about the order they will be returned to you. If you want that behavior you will need to use a data structure which supports stable iteration order, e.g. List.

Comment: `LinkedHashSet` is one such `Set` implementation. It guarantees the elements are returned in the order they were inserted.